# Disabling span hover

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists

I would like to disable the hover effect on the span.

Li:hover goes well, but when rolling over the span, the effect still working and that's what i don't want.

On the example, **i want the days in color when the cursor is over "calendar" but black when the cursor is over them**.

```css
#topnav li:nth-child(1) a:hover{
 color:#ff0000;
 }

#topnav li:nth-child(2) a:hover{
 color:#FF77FF;
 }

 #topnav li:nth-child(3) a:hover{
 color:#55FFFF;
 }
  
  #topnav li:hover span{
 color:#ff0000;
 }

#topnav li:nth-child(2):hover span{
 color:#FF77FF;
 }

 #topnav li:nth-child(3):hover span{
 color:#55FFFF;
 }
```

```html
<div id="topnav">
<ul>
  <li><a href="a.html">Calendar</a><span> Monday</span></li>
  <li><a href="b.html">Calendar</a><span> Tuesday</span></li>
  <li><a href="c.html">Calendar</a><span> Wenesday</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/danielillo/290cLhuq/10)

Thanks

Comment: I think i didn't explain well the situation. I want the days colored when i'm over the word "calendar", but not when the cursor is over the days. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

You were hovering the LI and the span is a child within the span. Apply the hover to the anchortag instead

```
#topnav li:hover a{
   color:#ff0000;
}
```

Here is your new [**JFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/290cLhuq/6/)

Answer (score 0):

It appears your css styling has hover effect to change appearance on all nth-child(2) which is your span elements. Take it out.

```css
#topnav li:nth-child(1) a:hover{
 color:#ff0000;
 }
```

```html
<div id="topnav">
<ul>
  <li><a href="a.html">Calendar</a><span> Monday</span></li>
  <li><a href="b.html">Calendar</a><span> Thursday</span></li>
  <li><a href="c.html">Calendar</a><span> Wenesday</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```